# collection of date using generics

Tags: java, generics, effective-java

I am reading about Generics in Effective Java item 23. It is mentioned as below:

> While the prospect of accidentally inserting a coin into a stamp
>   collection may appear far-fetched, the problem is real. For example,
>   it is easy to imagine someone putting a `java.util.Date` instance into a
>   collection that is supposed to contain only `java.sql.Date` instances.

I am not able to understand what does author mean by "it is easy to imagine someone putting a `java.util.Date` instance into a collection that is supposed to contain only `java.sql.Date` instances"?

```
Collection<java.util.Date> dateColl = new ArrayList();
String strDate = "2011-12-31 00:00:00";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
java.util.Date date = sdf.parse(strDate);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new Date(date.getTime());

dateColl.add(sqlDate);
```

Why above code is not throwing compilation error?

Comment: Better question:  why do you think it *should* be a compilation error?

Comment: sorry last statement is wrong it should be sqldate instead of date which is corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not able to understand what does author mean by "it is easy to
>   imagine someone putting a java.util.Date instance into a collection
>   that is supposed to contain only java.sql.Date instances"?

In your example :

```
Collection<java.util.Date> dateColl = new ArrayList();
java.util.Date date = sdf.parse(strDate);
...
dateColl.add(date);
```

you do the reverse. You declare a Collection of `java.util.Date`. And besides you have added a `java.util.Date` instance in the collection of `java.util.Date instance`. You never use the `java.sql.Date` instance you declare and of course adding a `java.util.Date` instance in a collection of `java.util.Date` doesn't require any cast and doesn't question about type compatibility.

In a OOP point of view : a `java.sql.Date` IS a `java.util.Date` type. So, it is legal :

```
Collection<java.util.Date> dateColl = new ArrayList();
dateColl.add(new java.sql.Date(...));
```

To understand the problem, you should declare  :

```
Collection<java.sql.Date> dateColl = new ArrayList();
```

and then try to add a java.util.Date instance. There, you will have a compilation problem since "you are putting a **java.util.Date** instance into a **collection that is supposed to contain only java.sql.Date instances**".

Without using generics in Collection classes, the compilation will not fail and therefore at the runtime, you may have `ClassCastException` if you expect to have a collection which contains only `java.sql.Date` instances :

Here, you will have a `ClassCastException` in the loop since you could not cast the `java.util.Date` instance to a `java.sql.Date` instance :

```
Collection mySqlDates = new ArrayList();
mySqlDates.add(new java.sql.Date(...));
mySqlDates.add(new java.util.Date(...));

for (Object object : mySqlDates) {
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = (java.sql.Date) object; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`date` is of type `java.util.Date`, which is the same type you declared your Collection for, so no error. However, `java.sql.Date` does extend `java.util.Date` so you should be able to store both versions in your Collection without issue.

Answer (score -1):

> Why above code is not throwing compilation error?

**Your collection `dateColl` is of type `java.util.Date` so you can add any object which is of either `java.util.Date` or of it's subtypes as shown below:**

```
Collection<java.util.Date> dateColl = new ArrayList();
String strDate = "2011-12-31 00:00:00";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
java.util.Date date = sdf.parse(strDate);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new Date(date.getTime());
dateColl.add(date); //VALID
dateColl.add(sqlDate);//VALID
```

Infact you can add `java.sql.Date` object as well as shown above (because `java.sql.Date` `extends` (IS-A) `java.util.Date`)

Comment: The OP is adding `date` to the collection, which is a `Date` object.  It's not that you're wrong, you're misreading the situation.